# Confusion about the different ways of writing Taylor Polynomials

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

For the sake of using a simple example, let's say I want to approximate $y=x^3$ with a second degree polynomial, and let's say I want to construct my polynomial around the point $x=4$.

One way I derive that polynomial $T_2(x)$ is such:

$T_2(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, $T_2(4)= 16a + 4b + c = 64$

$T_2'(x)= 2ax +b$, $T_2'(4)= 8a + b = 48$

$T_2''(x)= 2a$, $T_2''(x)= 2a =24$

**Then**,

$a = 12$, $b = -48$ and $c=64$, so that

$T_2(x)= 12x^2-48x+64$

**However**, I also know that Taylor polynomials are generalized as:

$T_2(x)= f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2} (x-a)^2$, which in this case would be:

$T_2(x)= 64 + 48 (x-a) + 12 (x-a)^2$

This last expression is almost the same as the previous one except that we have $48$ instead of $-48$.

Clearly the two expressions are almost identical, I just don't understand what makes that difference in the $x$ term coefficient.

I guess **I don't really understand how the generalized form is built**.

Comment: Don't forget to multiply out your term $ \ 12 \ (x-4)^2 \ $ in your second version: your two versions give the same quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate the Taylor polynomial around $a=4$ and you will get:

$$T_2(x) = 12(x-4)^2 + 48(x-4) + 64 = 12x^2 - 96x + 192 + 48x - 192 + 64 = 12x^2 - 48x + 64$$

Which is exactly what you got in the first step.

---

Assume that we can write a function $f$ as an infinite power series on a certain interval, around given center $a$, i.e. $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\inf} c_n(x-a)^n = c_0 + c_1(x-a) + c_2(x-a)^2 +...$. Now plug in $x=a$, which is in the interval and we have:

$$f(a) = c_0$$

Now differentiate and evaluate the derivative at the center. $f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\inf} nc_n(x-a)^{n-1} = c_1 + 2c_2(x-a) + 3c_3(x-a)^2 +...$

$$f'(a) = c_1$$

Now differentiate twice and evaluate the derivative at the center. $f''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\inf} n(n-1)c_n(x-a)^{n-2} = 2c_2 + 6c_3(x-a) + 12c_4(x-a)^2 +...$

$$f''(a) = 2c_2$$

Continuing like this you can derive a general formula $c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$. Hence:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how the generalized form is derived? Do you have to use integrals?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff I will update my answer soon.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff I wrote something about the derivation and you can see the outline of the proof aboce

Comment: Thank you for adding the proof, it makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: @jeremyradcliff No problem. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

$T(x)=f(a)+f′(a)(x−a)+\frac {f′′(a)}{2}(x−a)^2$

Near 4:

$x^3 \text{ ≈ } 64+ 48(x−4)+12(x−4)^2$